# Parsing local CSV file using Papaparse in Cordova iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, csv, papaparse

I'm using `Papaparse` and I'm trying to parse a CSV file which is saved in a folder within `www`.

It works well with `android` and `browser` platform.

However, when it comes to `iOS`, it returns the error callback.

When I output the error, it returns `undefined`.

I also checked whether the file path for iOS is correct, and the file does exist.

I have already tried setting the file path as `"folder/myfile.csv"` but since it resulted in an error, I tried to get its full path using the file plugin.

Anyone else encountered the same problem and have a workaround?

This is my code.

```
var getOldData = function() {
    var dir = "folder/myfile.csv",
        file = null;

    file = (isiOS) ? cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/" + dir : dir;

    Papa.parse(file, {
        download: true,
        error: function(err, file) {
            console.log(">>>> PAPA PARSE ERROR");
            console.log(">>>>" + err); // this returns undefined
            console.log(">>>>" + file); // this returns undefined as well
        },
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log(">>>> PAPA RESULTS");
            console.log(results);
        },
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load/issues/11) in pouchdb load on ios. It seems that

> ... for some reason, iOS is returning 0 as the status for the xhr request even when there is data loaded from file

So i changed in the papaparse `_chunkLoaded` function, this line

```
if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 400)
```

by this one:

```
if (!((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || (xhr.status==0 && xhr.responseText.length>0)))
```

And now it works.

I have added the same answer in the corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/320). 
May be this patch will be included.

Comment: This is like magic, haha I had to go through parsing the file separately using the FileReader API, and then calling Papaparse, but your answer is much better. Thanks! I hope they include the patch soon.